# Problem with text ellipsis in right to left languages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ellipsis

When I use the TextOverflow.ellipsis option in the Text widget it works perfectly in English, and in Hebrew without number.

When I add numbers to Hebrew Text the "..." is put right after the number.

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: ChosenHomeScreen()),
    );
  }
}

class ChosenHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget presentText(String text) {
    return Text(text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            presentText('english work without numbers perfectly'),
            presentText('english work with 123 number with no problem'),
            presentText('אאא 123 בבב 1232 גג 1232 דדד 1232 ההה'),
            presentText('אאא בבב גגג דד ההה ווו זזז חחח טטט '),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

my output:

[image]
Any solution ?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: didn't get any solution yet